# Cómo puedo contar la cantidad de columnas qe están ordenadas ascendente de una matriz . Estoy utilizando pascal

Tags: pascal

```
procedure ascendentes(n,m: byte ; mat: tipomat); 
var
i,j,suma: byte ;
  
  
  begin
    suma:=0;
    i:=2; 
  for j:=1 to m do 
     begin
       while (i<=n) and (mat[i,j]>mat[i-1,j]) do
         begin
           i:= i+1;
           suma:= suma+1;
         end;
     end; 
        writeln(i,'...',suma);
  if i> n then 
      writeln('cumple con ',suma)
  else
      writeln('no cumple ');
  end;
```

// No me calcula la cantidad bien de columnas.Estoy usando pascal

Comment: Hola, no explicas qué es lo que quieres obtener... qué es "calcular la cantidad de columnas", en otras palabras? Tampoco incluyes el tipo ```tipomat```, sin lo cual no se entiende del todo el código.

Comment: Hola! Lo que necesito obtener es cuantas  columnas de la matriz que por filas este ordenada de forma ascendente
 Tipomat=array[1..20,1..20] of real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no has desarrollado aún la lógica que resuelva correctamente el problema. Mi consejo es que, teniendo en cuenta el funcionamiento de un programa, resuelvas el problema primero utilizando papel y lápiz.

Una manera que a mi se me ocurre es declarar una variable booleana `EsAscendente` y, para cada columna, comenzar asumiendo que esta es ascendente e ir recorriéndola fila por fila. Si se encuentra un caso donde la casilla de la fila actual no sea mayor que la casilla de la fila anterior, establecer falso a dicha variable y abortar el ciclo que recorre las filas (no hace falta ver más filas, ya se sabe que la columna no es ascendente).

Al terminar dicho ciclo, si la variable `EsAscendente` tiene valor verdadero, incrementamos uno a la variable `Contador` y procedemos a la siguiente columna.

He hecho un ejemplo con un par de constantes y un tipo matriz llamado `TMatriz`:

```
const
  NumFilas = 5;
  NumColumnas = 5;
type
  TMatriz = array[1..NumFilas, 1..NumColumnas] of Integer;

procedure ContarColumnasAscendentes(const AMatriz: TMatriz);
var
  Fila, Columna: Integer;
  Contador: Integer;
  EsAscendente: Boolean;
begin
  Contador := 0;
  for Columna := 1 to NumColumnas do
  begin
    EsAscendente := True;
    for Fila := 2 to NumFilas do
      if AMatriz[Fila, Columna] <= AMatriz[Fila - 1, Columna] then
      begin
        EsAscendente := False;
        Break;
      end;
    if EsAscendente then Inc(Contador);
  end;
  Writeln;
  Writeln('La matriz tiene ', Contador, ' columnas en orden ascendente');
end;
```

Al ejecutar mi ejemplo completo, obtengo una salida como la siguiente:

```
Matriz:
   1   2   5   3  20
   2   4   4   6  19
   3   6   3   9  18
   4   8   2  12  17
   5  10   1  15  16

La matriz tiene 3 columnas en orden ascendente
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Tendré en cuenta tu consejo.